# Java Program, compile error: class is not abstract

Tags: java

When I Compile the code given below, it gives me an error:

> firstGUI is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener

Any help appreciated.

I use BlueJ to run my programs.

```
 //program using Buttons and Textfields
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 
public class firstGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    int l;
    JTextField tf = new JTextField("0",10);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Count");
   
      public firstGUI()
        {
          setTitle("Java Button");
          setVisible(true);
          setSize(600,600);
          SetDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);              
          tf.setEditable(false);
          b1.addActionListener(this);
          }

       public void main(String[] args)
       {
        firstGUI obj = new firstGUI();

          }
      @Override
      public void cal(ActionEvent e)
     { l++;
      tf.setText(l+"");}

     }
  }
```

Comment: "*How to run java Program perfectly with Compile Error: class is not abstract*" - You cannot run a program perfectly with a compilation error.

Comment: I meant : how to make it error free

Comment: and I posted this question for help not for pointing errors in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to rename your method `public void cal(ActionEvent e)` to `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`. The Problem is that the function named in the error message was not found, because you gave it a different name.

**Edit:** Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) for more information on abstract classes and inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to implement some interface in your class like in your example

```
public class firstGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
```

you should provide own implementation of method that are declared in used interface and in `ActionListener` you have:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{
    // your code
}
```

Or rename your method `public void cal(ActionEvent e)` to `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` to match contract form `ActionListener` interface.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a class as concrete class, if you are extending an abstract class or implementing an interface, its necessary that you provide implementation for all abstract methods. If any method is left in an abstract class/interface - the class will not be considered concrete and need to be marked as abstract.

*The error clearly mentions that you need to override (provide implementation) for the mentioned method - only after that you will be able to compile (& run) your code.*

Answer (score 0):

Any concrete (i.e. non-abstract) class that implements an interface needs to supply the methods specified by that interface. Since your class is declared to implement an interface, but it doesn't supply the required method, the class cannot be instantiated, and therefore would need to be declared `abstract` in order to compile.

Essentially, if your class is supposed to implement `ActionListener`, it should have an [`actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29) method.